# Django сделать в форме поле с выбором

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать форму с полем для выбора(скрин).
Данное поле должно содержать выбор существующих групп в БД. Спасибо заранее

Модель Group

```
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал таким методом но никак

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    group_exists = Group.objects.values('title')
    group = forms.ChoiceField(choices= group_exists, required=False)
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length= 4, required=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

используй `ModelChoiceField`

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), required=False)
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length= 4, required=True)
```

а еще лучше, если у тебя есть модель `Post` содержащая указанные поля, то используй ModelForm

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"# либо укажи перечень нужных тебе полей
```

подробней про ModelForm можно прочитать в документации https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Да, уже понял что через ModelForm нужно, модель Post имеется. Но первый пример тоже сохраню. Спасибо огромное)